# Java: Request and Response Objects which is the best design pattern for an Application

Tags: java, model-view-controller, design-patterns, web-applications, factory-pattern

**Please help me in choosing a very best design pattern for a web application..**

I have "request and response" parameters which came from a Java Servlet call.. how to design my class so that i can do it effectively, re-usability and to add customized code to serve the response back to the application.

There are around 15 action types basing on the condition i need to do some business logic and  PLSQL calls..

Initially I though of to use Factory design pattern for this 15 actions to create 15 classes and to serve the request in a static method having a new instance of 15 diff. classes. Even i got MVC in my mind to design.. but here there is no framework its pure Servlet handling..

But now I decided, before doing the modification I want to know which is the best design pattern to follow

> *by the by one more question is it good way if i pass the request and response as parameter to the business logic classes and do the modifications ?*

Comment: You should no be passing your request and response objects to business layer.You have to obtain values from your request at servlet level and pass those values to business layer.

Comment: well i know that we should not pass request and response which is a bad design approach anyhow its done by senior people so i can suggest that... but here i'm looking for a best design pattern for my application to handle 15 different actions ... how can i design this very effectively ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 to @Renjith's comment about not mixing business logic into the servlet level, but if you want to work directly with servlet's request and response objects, I suggest you take a look at [servlet filters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) and [HttpServletRequestWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html).

Comment: I understand that mixing business logic into servlet is not a good approach .. but my main concern is what is best design pattern i can choose for my problem which i mention.. please help me in this ..